# How to find a command identifier in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I can see commands list by pressing `ctrl+shift+p`. The list however shows only human-readable titles (`Foo Bar`), not command identifiers (`editor.foo.bar`). How do I find the identifiers?

If no one knows a generic way, maybe someone knows the identifier of `Debug: Start Debugging` command?

P.S. I need this for extension development, i.e. launching the command from my extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Preferences > keyboard shortucts there you have a bunch of commands >
>   right click > copy command `workbench.action.debug.start` is the one you
>   want

Credits to Isidor Nikolic